# How to get the nested model from parent scope?

Tags: scope, angularjs

Html code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Outer: {{aaa.bbb}}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
    <h1>Inner1: {{$parent['aaa']}}</h1>
    <h1>Inner2: {{$parent['aaa.bbb']}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Angularjs code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.aaa = {
    bbb:'Freewind'
  }
});

app.controller('InnerCtrl', function($scope){
});
```

The rendered html will be:

```
Outer: Freewind

Inner1: {"bbb":"Freewind"}

Inner2:
```

You can see the `Inner2:` is empty.

How can I show it?

Here is a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7IfxgsNCaUpKH9HOpr26?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InnerCtrl` scope inherits the properties from its parent scope (`MainCtrl` scope), therefore you can access those properties directly:

```
<div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
    <h1>Inner1: {{aaa}}</h1>
    <h1>Inner2: {{aaa.bbb}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That's normally not a good idea... Nevertheless, change the "Inner2" to `$parent['aaa']['bbb']` and it will work.

Comment: Or `$parent.$eval('aaa.bbb')`, but I don't know if it's the best solution

Comment: Do you really need to use `$parent`? It just seems wrong to have it there.

Comment: why $parent and for that matter WHY $parent.$eval. There is a reason scopes inherit from parents and there is a reason for why they are plain javascript objects, use those built-in features. Could you provide a real scenario where you can't accomplish a task except with $parent?

Comment: Because I want to define a directive(with `scope:new`), which will show some data of parent scope by name. If parent and current scope both have a model which have the same name by accident, I have to use `$parent` to show the model from parent only.

Comment: By `scope:new` do you mean `scope: true` or `scope: { ... }`? The first one creates a new scope that prototypically inherits from its parent. The second one creates a new isolate scope (no prototypical inheritance). If you are using the second one, why not send a model with the necessary information to the directive. For example: `<directive parent-data="yourDataModel">` and on the directive `scope: { parentData: '=parentData' }`. You could then use that information to check the "parent" (`parentData`) for properties with the same name.

Comment: If you are concerned about the possibility of name clashes between parent and child scopes, use an isolate scope in your directive, or adopt a naming convention that would avoid clashes (e.g., prepend all directive child scope properties with the name of the directive followed by an underscore).  Also note that child scope hiding/shadowing of parent scope properties only happens when working with primitives.  The Angular creators recommend using objects for your models, so that these types of problems are avoided.

Comment: @bmleite, sorry, I mean `scope:true`